# How to implement a drag and swap effect in CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, css, position

All:

Right now, say I have 4 DIV elements on the page, what I want to implement is drag a one DIV and move to other DIV then they can swap position just like IPHONE, when you hold the icon for a little while, all the icons turn into position edit mode, you can move icon around the screen and located to certain grid position and according icon can swap with it.

Could anyone show me an example for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery UI makes this trivial:

https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable

http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#default

The link also shows an example of how to use it.

Comment: Thanks, this is almost it! Do you have any tutorial to quick start?

Comment: I don't know of any tutorials. If you click on the "View Source" button on either link you can just look at the code and see how they use it.

Comment: Thanks, I ask this because when I tried that  jUI,  most time, it does not work as expected, say we have 4 DIV in the page layout 2X2, when we swap the first on with the last one(diagnal swap, it will like a shift: the second will move to the first place, the third to second the last to third)

Comment: I don't really understand what is happening but I suggest you ask another question and explain what is happening and add code. It's much more likely for you to get help with the specific issue your having if you add code to the question.